# How to place random elements in a HTML document using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I´m developing a Javascript game and I have to place random coins in the HTML document. I have used this code so far:

```
 createCoin() {
    section=document.createElement("div");
    section.innerHTML='<img src="./img/coin.png"/>';
    document.body.appendChild(section);
 }
```

This code simply places an image coin in the coordinates (0,0) of the document. What I want to do is access that recently created "div" and give it a random coordinate that I generate in another function so if I call several times the createCoin it creates several coins in the document. I can't use jQuery. Any ideas?

Comment: use Math.Random to generate a random value between a range of numbers & use those coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `createCoin` return the div and then use it.

```
createCoin() {
    section=document.createElement("div");
    section.innerHTML='<img src="./img/coin.png"/>';
    document.body.appendChild(section);

    section.style.position = 'absolute';
    section.style.left = '0px'; // units ('px')  are unnecessary for 0 but added for clarification
    section.style.top = '0px';

    return section;
 }
```

e.g.: `var coin = createCoin(); coin.style.left = ???; coin.style.top = ???;`

Comment: If I give numbers to .left and .top doesn't work. In fact, doing an alert of (coin.style.left) returns void. Isn't it a way to change manually the attributes of the div I've just created? Thanks anyway!

Comment: You need the unit -- either 'px' or '%'.  And the div, then, needs absolute positioning to set them.  I made assumptions that you were doing this already but perhaps I should not have made those assumptions.  see my edits.

Answer (score 2):

after create div element with id='coin' , to give the random position to div, use this:

```
<div id="coin" style="position:absolute">coin image</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function newPos(){
    var x=Math.random()*1000;
    x=Math.round(x);
    var y=Math.random()*500;
    y=Math.round(y);
    document.getElementById("coin").style.left=x+'px';
    document.getElementById("coin").style.top=y+'px';
}
newPos();
</script>
```

we consider that createCoin() function execute once, on the onload() event. and then the newPos() function must be run.